# Can an update function common to more than one property reveal which property is using it?

Tags: python

I'd like to use the same update function for several properties but I will need to know which property calls this function like in this script exemple.

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Panel, PropertyGroup
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, PointerProperty

def update_function(self, context):
    #if firstProp use this function:
    #   do this
    #elif secondProp use this function:
    #   do that


class MyCollectionProperty(PropertyGroup):

    firstProp = BoolProperty(
            name = "Fisrt",
            default = False,
            update = update_function,
            )

    secondProp = BoolProperty(
            name = "Second",
            default = False,
            update = update_function,
            )

class TestPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "test_panel"
    bl_label = "Test Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "category"

    def draw(self, context):
        myProps = context.window_manager.myProps
        layout = self.layout

        layout.prop(myProps, "firstProp")
        layout.prop(myProps, "secondProp")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.WindowManager.myProps = PointerProperty(type = MyCollectionProperty)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.myProps
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Is this possible or are we obliged to create a function per property?

Comment: I think the sample about "countries" here can help you: https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface

Comment: @lemon That's for operators, not properties.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def update_function(self, context, origin):
    if origin == 'firstProp':
        #   do this
    elif origin == 'secondProp':
        #   do that


class MyCollectionProperty(PropertyGroup):

    firstProp = BoolProperty(
            name = "Fisrt",
            default = False,
            update = lambda s, c: update_function(s, c, 'firstProp'),
            )

    secondProp = BoolProperty(
            name = "Second",
            default = False,
            update = lambda s, c: update_function(s, c, 'secondProp'),
            )
```

use a lambda, which passes the 'origin' to the update_function.

An update_function that prints out the value of the property

```
def update_function(self, context, origin):
    # - use "origin" argument to pass the member variable being modified
    # - "self" will refer to the instance of the MyCollectionProperty
    print(origin, ':' , getattr(self, origin))  

    if origin == 'firstProp':
        #   do this
    elif origin == 'secondProp':
        #   do that
```